# What are the benefits to using multiple LVM caches?

Tags: lvm, cache

I strangely can't find any documentation on this, just how to use LVM cache for a device.  If add another SSD as a second LVM cache to LVM volume, will I get better or worse performance?  Or does it only matter if the new SSD is faster, in which case, how useful would the old SSD then?

Answer (score 1):

There are many types of SSDs. You can find the answer based on the difference between the type of SSD and the amount of IOPS you are currently using, and the type and amount of IOPS you are going to install.

IOPS is a parameter that measures the speed of the storage unit. Accordingly, IOPS is the maximum read / write speed that the storage unit can perform in one second. Of course, this parameter alone is not enough. It is also the most fundamental factor in Disk Throughput speed. If you only focus on storage as performance, these two basic parameters are important.

With the test known as the 4K test, you can compare IOPS between disks. Below is the formula for calculation:

```
IOPS = (Read / Write Speed ​​(MBps) / Kilobytes per IO) * 1024
```

From here, you can theoretically measure the IOPS capacity for both drives. The 4K test gives the total amount of IOPS per second. These values ​​are also available on the manufacturers' data sheets, and manufacturers calculate them with different formulas.

The purpose of using the server is effective in choosing the disk. For example, if you are going to host a database, the write and read speeds should be at the closest values. If you are hosting a web page, it is preferable to have a fast reading speed. If you are using it as a log server, it is preferable to have a high write speed.

After giving general information, you can quickly see the instant IOPS values ​​of the disks on the server with the `[sysstat][1]` you will install on your system.To use `iostat`, you need to install `sysstat`.

You can use `[iostat][1]` for this. When you type iostat, you can see your CPU average, Kernel version and disk data.

**Device: tps kB_read / s kB_wrtn / s kB_read kB_wrtn**

Here you can filter the necessary information with `grep` and `awk`.`tps` returns the IOPS value. If you have a large number of disks and would like to know the instantaneous IOPS of a disk;

```
iostat -d sdX (or mdX etc.) | grep sdX | awk '{print $ 2;}'
```

The number included in the results shows the amount of IOPS delivered to the device per second. Of course, this is the data actively taken from the disk in the process.

IOPS and Disk Output speed are important in SSD disk selection. There are many types of M.2, NVMe, Sata.

I think it will be sufficient to define a single cache.Choosing SSD in LVM cache will contribute to performance. Here I tried to understand that choosing SSD alone is not enough with issues such as IOPS, Disk Throughput and Server purpose. I think it will be sufficient to define a single cache. If you have questions, you can add them as a comment.

Comment: This is a very nice write up to answer "how do I choose an SSD for a cache" but that wasn't my question.  My question was about using both SSDs as caches for a single volume.

Comment: Hello @cheezsteak, I tried to give a general information. Can this article help you? https://superuser.com/questions/952016/how-can-i-use-one-lvmcache-cache-pool-lv-for-multiple-origin-lvs

Comment: That article is for using one cache device for multiple volumes.  I was talking about using multiple cache devices for a single volume.  Turns out, you can't cache a volume twice so there's no point to my question anyways.